# MapActivity with loader framework

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-support-library

Is there any solution for using the a `MapView` (and thus the `MapActivity`) with the honeycomb pre-3.0 compatibility `Loader` library (and thus `FragmentActivity`)?

(as an aside, I never quite understood why one needed to extend `MapActivity` in order to use the map - it's terribly limiting when writing generic activities. Wouldn't an interface be more appropriate?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Carter Jernigan's suggestion received out-of-band, I ended up taking the source of the compat library and put a copy of everything in the `android.support.v4.app` package into my own source tree under the package `android.support.v4_map.app`. Then I modified the `FragmentActivity` to inherit from `MapActivity` instead of `Activity` and named it `MapFragmentActivity`. It's a fairly crude hack, but it works well (so far). I now have all the benefit of the `LoaderManager`.

As an aside, trying to use `CursorLoader`s without a `LoaderManager` is a recipe for lots of unclosed cursors.

Comment: So, and what do you do when there is a release of new version of support library?

Comment: Make a diff of the changes you made from the original source and re-apply it on top of the new library's source. (Yes, it's a PITA)